# build openjpeg under vc 2013

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2013, jpeg2000

Just wondering how to build openjpeg successfully under Windows 7 and visual studio 2013.
i try to install visual studio 6 witch is compatible of jpeg 2000 library but it is incompatible with window 7.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to build openjpeg-2.1.0 on Windows 7 with Visual Studio Express 2013 with cmake-2.8.12.2.  Make sure you allow cmake to itself to the `PATH` during installation. Once installed, run cmake from the command line in the root of the openjpeg directory. I had to use the `-DBUILD_THIRDPARTY:BOOL=ON` like so:

```
cmake -DBUILD_THIRDPARTY:BOOL=ON .
```

Once finished, you should be able to open any of the `.vcxproj` files in Visual Studio to build the project.